# automatic copy paste from Browser to Microsoft Word

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to copy some specific texts from internet browser(chrome) and want to paste them in proper fields of Microsoft word.. Let me explain what I want exactly...  I have this kind of page structure in chrome-

```
Name-Deepak,Raju,Jhon,Robert.......
Salary-200,254,673,953...
Phone-987535747,856889479,64688539,357954228....
```

Etc..

I have a table in MS word as-
Sl.       Phone.         Name.         Salary.

Can I make a auto copy paste program to make my table-

```
Sl.       Phone.           Name.           Salary
1.        987535747.       Deepak.         200
2. .......
```

Like this? Suggest me the best suitable platform to compile this.. Its best for me, if a bat file can do the job.. I know bit odd question.. And I should not ask the entire program,rather a section of it..Bt still.......  actually I don't know from where to start..

Comment: no chance to edit a word-file with batch. But you could write a pure text file and open it with word (of course it will have no formatting at all)

Comment: Its not coming in the way I have written the question.. In my table- "Sl. Phone. Name. Salary" are in one row.. And 1.  987535747.  Deepak.  200. Are in the next row..

Comment: So any other GUI based programs? Which one will you suggest? And tell me that is it even possible to do my job?

Comment: Possibilties: a) write a pure textfile (*.txt) and use it with Word or a similar program or b) write a pure textfile, (name it *.csv) which you can open with Excel (also no formatting) or c) use an external utility (there were some suggestions with AutoHotKey here, but I don't know it - seemss to be a sort of programmable "keystroke-and-mouse-emulator")

Comment: copy your data from the browser to a text file named "file.csv" and open it with excel. Google "excel swap columns and rows". If the structure in your example is correct, this should solve the biggest part of your problem. (I hope, it's a one-time-task?)

Comment: Correct me if I am missing something here. Are you requesting a batch script that would access a webpage, copy some specific texts from the page and append them as desired in word?

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover: exactly.. But, not necessarily bat script. Tell me, which script will be useful to do this job?

Comment: @Stephan: No.. I need something. Which will be totally automatic. It will save my lots of time and effort. The program I am looking for will copy some specified text(Ex-all data under 'Name' column)from web page and will paste to word(How ever, if it pastes the data to a txt file, thats also ok). My main problem is to go pages over pages, and collect the data.

Comment: ok, this shold be possible with batch (using wget.exe to read web pages), but I'm sure, batch is not the best way to do it. I think VBS will be far better for this, but that is beyond my horizont.

Comment: I have hard about vbs scripts for automatic typing. Bat is not essential.. Give me some ideas how to implement this thing in vbs.. Or, reffer someone, who can give me some ideas@Stephan

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a `wget` which will only retrieve the document, what you want is a way of parsing the results of the web content and writing into an output file.

After searching the web, I could only come across

1. [lynx](http://www.vordweb.co.uk/standards/download_lynx.htm) which
   is a text based browser and you can parse the `-dump` parameter to
   output the text into file which you can then write a script to do
   the final bit.

   Also take a look at this
   [link](http://lynx.isc.org/lynx2.8.7/lynx2-8-7/lynx_help/Lynx_users_guide.html)
   for more info on switches you can use most especially if the desired
   text has links in it (`-nolist`)
2. [elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/) which is an advanced text based browser

Comment: Lynx? Sounds interesting.. But,Is there any way to grab contents from normal browser like chrome?

Comment: Grab contents from Chrome? So you are saying the script or code should launch the site first with Chrome and then grab the contents and process as desired. Sorry this is out of my rimit